# Using different GCC to build Linux vs Linux Apps

Tags: c, linux, gcc

This question may seem weird for some gurus out there, but I'm a little perplexed.
Basically what I want to do is to evaluate different tool chain for developing applications on embedded Linux. Say I have my Linux built using Yocto Project, which cross-compiles GCC from scratch can provide it as a cross toolchain for apps developers.

But if I want to try out different toolchains fro this point, say Sourcery CodeBench or a toolchain generated using BuildRoot, is it possible to build a applications using these toolchains and still run them on the Yocto-generated Linux? I'd imagine this is doable is built statically. But if we then want to link dynamically, it's simply a matter of copying over libc?

Thanks for the help. Sorry if question is ambiguous.

Comment: I'd worry more about compiler specific startup code, e.g. `libgcc` type stuff.

Comment: usually, there is no startup code in `libgcc`, this is merely to support processor/platform differences/missing features (like e.g. longword multiplies) to gcc's needs. Startup code is in `crtbegin.o`, usually. Basically, you should be able to use any toolchain for kernel _and_ application development, as long as they generate code for the same ABI. Differences may exist in linker scripts, and startup code, however.

Comment: So it turns out I asked this question pre-maturely. Following Sourcery's guide on HOST=Linux TARGET=IA32, GCC supports flags called -rpath and --dynamic-linker options. This way I don't need to overwrite any preexisting sysroot.